# Replace Spaces with Underscores in Screwturn Wiki links

Tags: screwturn

When adding an internal link which has a space to a Screwturn Wiki page, the created link replaces the spaces with %20

**Example:**

```
  [Link to a page]
```

will be converted to:

```
  [Link%20to%20a%20page|Link to a page]
```

when saved. This results in an ugly url:

```
http://wikihost/wiki/Link%20to%20a%20page.ashx
```

Other wiki systems I've used replace spaces with an underscore (_)

Is there a way to make Screwturn Wiki replace spaces with underscore (_) automatically, instead of %20?

Comment: I spotted this my self the other day I suggest you report the problem to http://stw.codeplex.com